# Curl_exec starts immediately after loading the page. How to fix that?

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm building one basic webpage with some forms that would send Firebase push notifications to an Android app. Everything works fine, except one thing. Every time I load the page, the notification is sent right at the page initiation. That is, before even filling in the form.

I have then added an `if` condition so that when the form is empty (e.g. `$_POST['message'] == NULL`), `curl_exec` would not be triggered. It works fine like this, but I have a lot of **Notice:** messages when loading the page. I can easily ignore that, but I can see now that when I refresh the page, the data in the forms stays the same. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

The code is given below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Firebase Push Notification</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
    
        <hr />
        <form action="" method="post">
         
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="title">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Content:</label>
            <textarea required="" class="form-control" rows="2" id="message" placeholder="Content" name="message"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="destinatia">Where to open?:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="destinatia" required> 
                            <option value="first_page">First page</option> 
                            <option value="events">Events</option> 
                            </select>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
        </form>

      </div>

      <?php
define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAA0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$msg = array
(
'body' => $_POST['message'],
'title' => $_POST['title'],
'priority' => 'high',
'vibrate' => 100,
'sound' => 'default',
'click_action' => $_POST['destinatia'],
//'time_to_live' => 3600
);

$fields = array('to' => '/topics/CHECK', 'notification' => $msg);

$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
if($_POST['message'] == NULL){
 echo 'Empty';}
else {
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 echo 'Not empty';
 curl_close($ch);
 echo '<h2>Checking:</h2><hr/><h3>Sent:</h3><p><pre>';
 echo json_encode($fields,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 echo '</pre></p><h3>ID</h3><p><pre>';
 echo $result;
 echo '</pre></p>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Put the PHP code in the separate file and then use the ajax call on window ready.

Comment: So the question is how to get rid of notices about undefined indices? If so use `!empty()`, or `isset`, depending on the acceptable values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef